# How to properly load and use pre-trained model in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

I am loading a pre-trained model and try to use it for transfer learning. When I pass the input shape to the imported model, I receive `Layer.call` error. Can anyone recommend how to solve this error?

```
#loading the trained model
dir= "E:/Notebooks/trained models/VMB"
model_cnn=tensorflow.keras.models.load_model(dir)

input=tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(16,16,3))
model_tr=Sequential() #model_tr: model for transfer learning
model_tr.add(model_cnn(input_shape= input))
model_tr.add(Flatten())
model_tr.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model_tr.summary()
```

error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-23e4817781ea> in <module>
      3 
      4 model_tr=Sequential() #model_tr: model for transfer learning
----> 5 model_tr.add(model_cnn(activation='relu',input_shape= input))
      6 model_tr.add(Flatten())
      7 model_tr.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

~\Anaconda-3\envs\myspatialenv-new\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    965     # - mixed precision casting (autocast) is only applied to `inputs`,
    966     #   not to any other argument.
--> 967     inputs, args, kwargs = self._split_out_first_arg(args, kwargs)
    968     input_list = tf.nest.flatten(inputs)
    969 

~\Anaconda-3\envs\myspatialenv-new\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _split_out_first_arg(self, args, kwargs)
   3010     else:
   3011       raise ValueError(
-> 3012           'The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.')
   3013     return inputs, args, kwargs
   3014 

ValueError: The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.
```

Comment: `model_cnn` gets input tensor and return the output. It is not a layer and therefore you can not pass `input_shape` or `activation` argument to it, unless you have a custom model. Anyway, you can only use it like `model.add(model_cnn)`. Note that you should consider the structure of `model_cnn` to see if is it reasonable to add some flatten and dense layers after it or not.

Comment: Did you tried as suggested above?